# Qué expresión regular usar en JavaScript, al validar una cadena de más de 3 caracteres en minúscula, para que empiece y termine con la misma vocal?

Tags: javascript, regex, validación

Abbc -- false

achA -- false

aje -- false

oho -- true

uttu -- true

Gracias a todos por adelantado!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te recomiendo revisar [ask] e incluir un [mcve] si quieres que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Luego puedes [edit] tu pregunta y enfocar las preguntas respecto a lo que hayas intentado, ya que las preguntas que no demuestran esfuerzo no son bien recibidas y probablemente termine cerrada si no agregas más detalles.

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que lleves hecho

Comment: "caracteres en minúscula" es una definición ambigua, ¿Qué sucede por ejemplo con los números? Porque estos no tienen "minúscula". Si incluye a todos los caracteres que pueden tener minúscula habría que incluír ñ, á, û, ç, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes usar esta expresion por ejemplo, solo para letras desde la "a" a la "z"

```js
let regExp = /^([a-zA-Z]).*\1$/

console.log(regExp.test("aeioua"))
// true
console.log(regExp.test("aeioui"))
// false
```

Comment: Esa expresión admite mayúsculas y la pregunta dice "más de 3 caracteres en minúscula".

Comment: De acuerdo con el  titulo de la pregunta  la cadena a evaluar son letras  minusculas pero la expresión evalúa la primera letra contra la última sea vocal o no. "test". o "TesT"  y no necesariamente minuscula: AeiouA tambien data verdadero.